# How to install Gnome Shell Extension "Night light slider" & "Pause night light" with apt

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, gnome3, gnome-shell

If i type "night..." into my global search window, `software` recommends the 2 packages: `Night light slider` and `Pause night light`.

[image]

How do I install this packages with `apt`?

I have done some `apt search ...` searches and did not find anything:

```
apt search nightlight #outputs nothing
apt search night light #outputs 3 packages not related to the mentioned ones
apt search pause night #outputs nothing
apt search night slider #outputs nothing
```

My Distribution and Kernel:

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-1-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
       GNOME Shell: 3.26.2
```

[Pause Night Light on extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1327/pause-night-light/)
[Night Light Slider on extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/)

There is a package called `redshift` that adjusts the color temperature of the screen, still not what I am looking for.

I thought `software` would recommend packages from the *package-list* that is the same as being used by `apt`, is this wrong?

Comment: [Maybe in `gnome-settings-daemon`](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786569)?